# How to test convergence for a tetration series slightly below the harmonic series?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have the following series to test convergence
\begin{align}
S_{\infty}=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\dfrac{1}{n}
\left(
\dfrac{1}{n}
\right)^{
\left(
\dfrac{1}{n}
\right)
}
<
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\dfrac{1}{n}
\ ,
\end{align}
however it has several annoying properties that make it difficult to test convergence such as its derivatives create $\ln(n)$ terms, its terms are non-integrable in terms of a known function, and its finite sum is slightly below the harmonic series.

How does one test convergence for a tetration series slightly below the harmonic series?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see in which way "tetration" is involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[^n]n=1$.

Comment: $\boldsymbol{\text{Hint:}}$ $ e \geq \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n}$?

Comment: @linuxfreebird: See [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).